# How to retrieve lists items with JavaScript in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have two SharePoint permissions groups:

- HR
- Employee

The `Employee` permission group does not have access to view the list, but I need to retrieve list items in a page.

How can I retrieve list items with JavaScript from that list that I do not have access?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SharePoint JavaScript object model, It is not possible,because JSOM OR REST run under current user context. So if current user don't have permission on particular list then it is not possible to retrieve item from that list using current user who is not able to access this list.

Answer (score 1):

please refer the below article by MSDN. I hope that would help you to solve your problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx